# the explanation of cuda has lots of '\p'

Tags: cuda

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t count, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind);

/**
 * \brief Copies memory between two devices
 *
 * Copies memory from one device to memory on another device.  \p dst is the 
 * base device pointer of the destination memory and \p dstDevice is the 
 * destination device.  \p src is the base device pointer of the source memory 
 * and \p srcDevice is the source device.  \p count specifies the number of 
 */
```

as you can see above,there are lots of "\p" in cuda explanation, i just wonder what does it mean?THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll notice they are contained in comments, right?

They are text keys for an auto-documentation system that identifies "the next thing is a function parameter".

The way you have excerpted this is also confusing because the comment section applies to the function prototype that follows the comment, not the one that precedes the comment.